# Google Analytycs log, sent as Post / Get request

Tags: firebase, post, request, firebase-analytics

We need to send logs to Google Analytics, but due to the restrictions in some countries we can't use the official Firebase SDK and mobile code like Analytics.logEvent.

We tried the simple POST requests to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect, but the server always returns code Success 200, though the data isn't uploaded as logs.

We guess that some data is missing, like the one in GoogleService-Info.plist file, but we don't know how to add it to the POST request.
So we need to ask if someone has implemented this communication by using POST / GET protocols ?

Probably Google have removed the description online, so that the people would use their official recommended Firebase SDK.

Thus I would appreciate response to my email too.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can anyone advise me how to find on the dashboard the data, sent by users ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the new [Measurement Protocol for Google Analytics 4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4), which allows you to send events directly to Google Analytics by making HTTP calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I read it and set some parameters the way they were described - but unfortunately without success so far.
Do you happen to have some example with sample data, that I can use ?

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Anyway the best answer so far was given by a colleague of mine who said: encode your request as a Get request by appending the parameters using ? and &. Then send it as Post. But I'm still trying to find how to see on the dashboard the data, sent by users.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your question is tagged with "firebase-analytics".  [Firebase Analytics is now part of Google Analytics 4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10089681?hl=en).  The URL "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect" is the endpoint for the legacy Google Analytics product, not Google Analytics 4.  There is  a different endpoint for Google Analytics 4.

Are you trying to send data for a Universal Analytics property (starts with "UA") or a newer Google Analytics 4 property (formerly known as App+Web)?  You could use [Measurement Protocol for Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1) if it's a Universal Analytics property.